# jquery form elements to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, loops, each

I'm trying to get all form elements to array, then loop through them using jquery's $.each() function and within this function get each element's id, and title attributes.

I've tried serializeArray(), but I can only get 'name' and 'value' attributes.

I need something that collects all form elements whether it's input (regardless of the type), select, textarea, and regardless whether it has value, is checked or hidden.

Perhaps something like $('#form_id').find('input select textarea'); ?

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: *Perhaps something like `$('#form_id').find('input select textarea');`?* ... go ahead and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#form_id')[0].elements
```

It will return a nodeList containing all form-elements.

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $.each($('#form_id')[0].elements,
           function(i,o)
           {
            var _this=$(o);
            alert('id:'+_this.attr('id')+'\ntitle:'+_this.attr('title'));
           })

  }
);
```

---

**<edit>

Please Note: the elements-collecttion may also contain elements like fieldset or object, See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed

</edit>**

Comment: that's fine - this is just for the initial validation (client side) - server side has more in depth filtration of all submitted variables

Answer (score 3):

You can get all form elements with the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) pseudo class:

```
var elems = $('#form_id').find(':input'); // changed this line
```

Comment: isn't this one going to only collect 'input' elements?

Comment: No, this is a pseudo class that matches all form elements (input, select, textarea, everything)

Comment: How is it performance-wise comparing to the suggestion above ($('#form_id')[0].elements) ?

Comment: regardless of any benchmarks I guess elements should be mouch faster, it's a native property of forms, nothing to collect.

Comment: Don't use `:input` anymore, [it will be removed in the future](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9400).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work the way you want:

```
$('#form_id').children('input, select, textarea')
```

Comment: This will match only immediate children

Comment: Use `find` instead of `children`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this function

```js
$.fn.serializeAssoc = function() {
    var formData = {};
    this.find('[name]').each(function() {
        formData[this.name] = this.value;  
    })
    return formData;
};

//And Use it like this

objArr = $('#FormID').serializeAssoc();
```

Comment: this will return Associated array with key and value, where key is the form field name and the value is its value in the form.